# How to validate loop value in php? column 1 > column 2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSydv.png)

The above image due value 19948 and the input value are not greater than the due value 19948. How to validate this in javascript or jquery or php?

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$sql = "select * from invoice where `cid`='5'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($res);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

        $i = $i + 1;

        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>" . $row['customername'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['totalamount'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['paidamount'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['dueamount'] . "</td>";

        ?>


        <?php

        echo "<td><input type='text' name='ichange$i' value='0'  onkeyup='ivalue()'  />
                      <input type='hidden' name='idue$i' value='$due'   /></td>";
        echo "</td>"; 

        echo "</tr>";

}

 echo "<input type='hidden' name='nrows' value='$numrows' />";

?>

 <script>

     function ivalue()
    {

        nrows=document.getElementsByName("nrows").item(0).value;

        for(i=1;i<=nrows;i++)
        {
            ichange="ichange" + i;
            idue="idue" + i;

            if(document.getElementsByName(ichange).item(0).value>document.getElementsByName(idue).item(0).value)    
            {
               alert("Value not greater than due value")

            }


        }


    } 

</script>
```

Comment: Show us your code by editing your question.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @KarlRichter Please check above code

Comment: The absense of verbs predicates makes it hard to understand your question - regardless of whether you're a native speaker or not.

Comment: do you have any other example for loop input value validaton in jquery or javascript?

I have two value

Name    Total Amount       Due Amount            Input value
xxxx          1000                      500                       textbox here
xxxx1        1500                      100                       textbox here

I need to validate Input value not greater than due amount value

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to alert the user if he enters a greater value than the due in the same row.
I would use jQuery here since you tagged it :

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup',function(){
    if($(this).val() > $(this).next().val()){
        alert("Value not greater than due value")
    }
})
```

You could add some classes to your html for an easier and more precise select.